# Not getting custom header value exposed in Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Tags: c++, cors, libcurl

I am using LibCurl/C++ to send and receive html requests. One of the servers I access returns back this header information Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom1, where X-Custom1 is a custom header to provide data that I need to parse. But I am not seeing any value for X-Custom1.

I tried requesting it specifically by adding
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Custom1
header in my curl c++ request. But no use.

Response header data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: <server name>
Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 06:43:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: <cookie data>; expires=Fri, 30-Sep-16 06:43:05 GMT; path=/;     domain=<domain name>; HttpOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom1
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Etag: W/"<tag data>"
CF-RAY: <ray data>
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Anyone know how to get the X-Custom1 data ? 
I have been stuck at this for a long time now and need help. 
Forgive me if this could be a cross post or wrongly tagged. I am not sure where else to post this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I have been asking the wrong question after all.The response merely says X-Custom1 will be accessible from the server. It turned out that I had to request an entirely different url to get the actual valid data for that header.

Posting it here to let others seeking out similar questions know how it turned out.